# Loading custom fonts doesn't work in Firefox 14

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I developed a site using Wordpress. I created my custom theme based on the existing twentyeleven.

I'm using custom fonts (.eot, .otf, .ttf) and they work PERFECT in every single browser except for Firefox.

This is what I get in my console:

[image]

I already added this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/truetype ttf
AddType font/opentype otf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
```

to my apache's config file.

my fonts are in /public_html/fonts

and my css looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Technic;
    src: url(/fonts/technic.eot); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url(/fonts/technic.otf);
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried woff files. I dont get a console error but the font is not being rendered! @Userpassword

Comment: Can you type font url in adress bar ? https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/303

Comment: Any error reports in the error console?

Comment: No ... NO error reports in the console